# Returned is not empty but says length is 0

Tags: typescript, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I'm returning data from firebase by using snapshots and pushing it to my own array. When i console.log it, it does have the elements in them, but console.log the length says 0.

```
getConnections( user ) {
    const connections = [];
    const connectionsRef = this.db.database.ref( this.dbPath + user.id + '/connections/');
    connectionsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach( childSS => {
                connections.push( childSS.child('personID').val() );
            });
    });
    return connections;
}



const connectionsOfUser = await this.chatService.getConnections( user );
            console.log(connectionsOfUser); // Gives result
            console.log(connectionsOfUser.length); // Shows 0
```

Comment: Since this code isn't a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE to demonstrate the issue, I'll just have to guess that this might have to do with [some browsers showing a live view of logged objects/arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Logging_objects)

Answer (score 1):

By the time your `return connections` runs, the `connections.push(...)` calls haven't run yet. So you always return an empty array. The `console.log(connectionsOfUser)` may **seem** to work, because Chrome dev tools updates the array when it is populated. If you want to see that what the value is at the moment, you can log it with `console.log(JSON.stringify(connectionsOfUser))`, which will show the empty array.

Your `await` doesn't work here because:

1. your `getConnections` is not marked as `async`
2. you're not returning a promise of a later array, but an empty array now.

A simple fix is to just use promises:

```
getConnections( user ) {
    const connectionsRef = this.db.database.ref( this.dbPath + user.id + '/connections/');
    return connectionsRef.once('value', snapshot => {
        const connections = [];
        snapshot.forEach( childSS => {
            connections.push( childSS.child('personID').val() );
        });
        return connections;
    });
}

this.chatService.getConnections( user ).then((connections) => {
    console.log(connectionsOfUser); // Gives result
    console.log(connectionsOfUser.length); // Shows 0
})
```

So here:

- We use `once` instead of `on`, since `on()` may fire multiple times, and we can only return a result once.
- We return the connections from inside the callback, and then bubble them up with another return in the top-level of the function.
- We then use `then()` in the calling code to get the connections.

---

You can probably now mark `getConnections` as async and then call it with `await` like you were trying:

```
const connectionsOfUser = await this.chatService.getConnections( user );
console.log(connectionsOfUser.length);
```